# Unable to Use String Result From AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The issue I am having is that I cannot seem to USE the result passed back to the original `JS` file from the `PHP` file called from the request. This is the result and handler:

```
if(creds_verification() == true){
        $.ajax({
        url:"scripts/scripts.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "post", //request type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {url: URL, user: USER, password: PASS},
        success:function(result){
            var verdict = result
            if(verdict == "Yes"){
               Call another external function 
            }else{
            console.log(results.abc)
         }
       }
     });
    }
```

The console is constantly printing "Yes", aka the result of `results.abc`... why would this happen? It SHOULD be executing the next function...

**Added Info**
`PHP` script running shell command and `echo`ing the result:

**scripts.php**

```
    <?php  
$URL = $_POST['url'];
$USER = $_POST['user'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['password'];

echo json_encode(array("abc" => shell_exec("PATH.../phantomjs PATH/phantom/examples/test.js 2>&1 $URL $USER $PASSWORD")));
?>
```

And the `JS` file this is calling from the shell command:

**test.js**

```
var system = require('system')
var page = require('webpage').create()
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
var URL = system.args[1]
var USER = system.args[2]
var PASS = system.args[3]
var steps = [
  function() {
    page.open('http://'+URL+'/login.html')
  },
  function() {
    page.evaluate(function(USER, PASS) {
      document.querySelector('input[name="log"]').value = USER
    document.querySelector('input[name="pwd"]').value = PASS
    document.querySelector('form').submit()
    }, USER, PASS)
  },
function(){
     var newURL = page.url
     if(newURL == 'http://'+URL+'/user.html'){
      console.log('Yes')
     }else{
      console.log('No?')
     }
}
]
var stepindex = 0
var loading = false

setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep, 5000)

function executeRequestsStepByStep(){
  if (loading == false && steps[stepindex]) {
    steps[stepindex]()
    stepindex++
  }
  if (!steps[stepindex]) {
    phantom.exit()
  }
}
page.onLoadStarted = function() { loading = true }
page.onLoadFinished = function() { loading = false }
```

Comment: not enough details

Comment: probably this: verdict == "Yes", doesn't evaluate to true and your function doesn't get called. log result.

Comment: Are you sure `verdict` is equal to `result`?, it seems you're overwriting the content.

Comment: always use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: @PaoloMangia it is not supposed to evaluate to true or false, rather check to see if the value of the result is equal to the string "Yes" and then respond accordingly.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma yes, absolutely, I checked this by logging both values individually

Comment: what i meant is: if verdict is equal to "yes" the whole statement is true so execute what's inside of it. @Ethan

Comment: @PaoloMangia Yes, I know this is the issue, hence why I posted this question. It SHOULD, but for some reason does not.

Comment: Can we know what result is? @Ethan also why aren't you checking if result.abc === "Yes" ? **note:** always use 3 equals "==="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the code you call on the server (this means the result of `scripts/scripts.php`) instead of returning 'Yes' as the result is putting the 'Yes' in the `abc` property of a returned object.

Change the php code to:

```
<?php  
$URL = $_POST['url'];
$USER = $_POST['user'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['password'];

$res = shell_exec("PATH.../phantomjs PATH/phantom/examples/test.js 2>&1 $URL $USER $PASSWORD");
echo json_encode($res == 'Yes' ? $res : array("abc"=>$res));
?>
```

**Edit** if the result of `test.js` is just "Yes" or "No" then change the PHP to

```
<?php  
$URL = $_POST['url'];
$USER = $_POST['user'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['password'];

$res = shell_exec("PATH.../phantomjs PATH/phantom/examples/test.js 2>&1 $URL $USER $PASSWORD");
echo json_encode(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $res));
?>
```

and the javascript to

```
if(creds_verification() == true){
        $.ajax({
        url:"scripts/scripts.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "post", //request type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {url: URL, user: USER, password: PASS},
        success:function(result){
            if(result == "Yes"){
               Call another external function 
            }else{
               console.log(result)
         }
       }
     });
    }
```

Comment: I made these changes, I also tried `if(result.abc == "Yes")`, but neither of them worked.

Comment: Wouldn't this always return Yes? It is supposed to return whatever the `test.js` determines ("Yes" or "No" ("No?" In the script above"))

Comment: No. It returns only "Yes" if the result is "Yes" OR it creates an array with an "abc" key with the value as the result of test.js otherwise.

Comment: If the result is just "Yes" or "No" then you don't need an `abc` property. Just return `echo json_encode($res);` and you're done. Then forget about `abc` at all in the javascript

Comment: I've made these changes, but the same situation is happening. The `else` parameter is firing, and printing `"Yes"` in the console

Comment: Change `console.log(result)` to `console.log('|' + result + '|')` and paste me the result please.

Comment: Prints  `|Yes
|` as in it is on a different line, something similar to like "/n" I believe it is

Comment: See my edit. Change the line in php to `echo json_encode(reg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $res));`

Comment: Now nothing is being printed to the console at all, in either instance of `"Yes"` or `"No"` being returned

Comment: Ups... typo sorry. it's `echo json_encode(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $res));`